# Themify Scrolling option

Tags: jquery, css

My website (decimategear.com) as well as (www.decimategear.com/product/shockblade-zed-shuriken/) uses a themify theme. I really like it and I dont want to change my theme at all. What really concerns me about this theme is that when you scroll on the page the elements scroll over eachother. I was wondering what I can do to disable this. I dont want the elements to ever overlap over eachother.

Do I edit a php/css file? If so which one contains the scrolling options for every page?

Answer (score 0):

This CSS tag

```
.parallax-header #sliderwrap,
.parallax-header.single-post #pagewrap .single-media-wrap,
.parallax-header.single-product #layout .product-single-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Is what I can see that is what I would suspect is causing your elements to overlap. Removing the `position: fixed;` would stop it

Thing is by removing the position fixed your breaking the parallax style of the theme.